# Identifier 'XXX' has already been declared in nuxt utils autoimport

Tags: nuxt.js

I created a class:

```js
import FirestoreManager from './FirestoreManager';
import type { ArtworkType } from '~/utils';

const DB_NAME = 'artworks';

class ArtworkManager extends FirestoreManager<ArtworkType> {
  
  static instance: ArtworkManager;

  constructor(dbName: string) {
    if (ArtworkManager.instance) {
      return ArtworkManager.instance;
    }
    super(dbName);
    ArtworkManager.instance = this;
  }

  // Método estático para obtener la instancia
  static getInstance() {
    if (!ArtworkManager.instance) {
      ArtworkManager.instance = new ArtworkManager(DB_NAME);
    }
    return ArtworkManager.instance;
  }

}

export { ArtworkManager }
```

To get autoimport in `~/utils/index.ts` I exported it:

```js
export { ArtworkManager } from './firebase/firestore/ArtworkManager';
```

#### Describe the bug

The problem that I have is importing a class (singleton) from utils.

I got this error:
[image]

It autoimports the class itself.

If I remove the export from `~/utils/index.ts` I got:
The requested module '/_nuxt/utils/index.ts?t=1711549824227' does not provide an export named 'ArtworkManager'

#### Additional context

I tried to move the 'ArtworkManager' class to `~/utils/` root, but I got the same results.

### Question

Is it the correct way to do it?
If not, what is the correct way to autoimport a class?

Link to Github reported as bug:
https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/26516